# Render html background image using itext in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, itext, background-image

I am parsing an HTML string to build an pdf file by using itext in asp.net. But my problem is i am not unable to render the background image in div tag.

HTML String

```
String data=" Hello<div style='background:url(http://localhost:64744/Openings.png);width:200px;height:300px;'></div>"
```

Default.aspx

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 10, 10);
System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, mStream);

                    /*****************************/

                    StringWriter swPdf = new StringWriter();
                    HtmlTextWriter hwPdf = new HtmlTextWriter(swPdf);
                    hwPdf.Write(Session["data"]); // get the above string

                    StringReader sr = new StringReader(swPdf.ToString());

                    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                    pdfDoc.Close();

                    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=COD.pdf");
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(mStream.GetBuffer(), 0, mStream.GetBuffer().Length);
                    //Response.BinaryWrite(mStream.ToArray());
                    Response.End();
```

Everything is fine my pdf is generated properly but without background image. So it is possible some way to get the background image using itext or any other dll

Comment: [itextsharp Working with images](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images)

Comment: Did you understand the question ? i need to render the background-image used in html style tag

Comment: Issue is may be related to the path of the image.

Comment: I know is may be path issue but i gave the same path on which my server is running

Comment: Just an FYI, `HTMLWorker` is obsolete, you should use `XMLWorker`.